# static selector between threads on nio server

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I need to implement a server in which has only one selector(static); multiple threads try to register channel to the same static selector.

I tried to implement the server, but the problem is that the static selector works for first time i.e. registers the channel; but on next call to register different channel the thread gets hanged.

I am sure the above explanation is very vague. but please co-operate. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057224/thread-is-stuck-while-registering-channel-with-selector-in-java-nio-server

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to explain where the static requirement comes from? static is typically a Bad Idea, except in specialized circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think selector is designed to be used by only a single thread so better to avoid registering from multiple threads. And, I think that doesn't work currently.